# How to pass this item.id value into axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/kam/:Id')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

I have a page called "*application.js*". Where I fetch all the data from the database. I have another page called *"detail.js"*. Where I want to redirect by clicking the "**DETAIL**" button from *"application.js"*. Into "*detail.js*" I have to fetch the data by ID. The ID must be that particular item that I have clicked from *"application.js"* file.
I want "`item.id`" value instead of `/:id` into `axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/kam/:Id')`.

[image: this is how the data is represented in application.js]

As you can see how the data represented in *"application.js"*. When I clicked on the "**DETAIL**" button it should carry `item.id` value.

Here is the code for the *"application.js"*:

```js
const PendingApplication = () => {
  //const { job } = props;
  let history = useHistory();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const handleClick = (location) => {
    console.log(location);
    history.push(location);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/kam")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setData(response.data.kamData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Ticket No</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Category</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Sub Category</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Request Time & Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Company Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Action</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell>{item.ticketno}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.approvecategory}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.subcategory}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.date}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.companyname}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button
                  color="#71BD44"
                  onClick={() => handleClick(`/detail/${item.id}`)}
                >
                  Detail
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PendingApplication;
```

When you click on this Button, it's going to exact ID address in browser.

```js
<Button color="#71BD44" onClick={() => handleClick(`/detail/${item.id}`)}>
  Detail
</Button>
```

But I want this `${item.id}` value into this `axios` instead of `:id`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/api/kam/:id")

    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setData(response.data.kamData);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

This `useEffect` code is from "*detail.js*".

Can anyone help me? How to do that?

Comment: Where, or how, does this `Detail` component then access the `id` value? Can you update your question to include all relevant code? What routing/navigation is the app using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `Details` component has access to the `id` route match param you can use a string template to "inject" the `id` value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/kam/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setData(response.data.kamData);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

If you are using `react-router-dom` then you can use the [generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath) utility to generate the GET request URL.

```
import { generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

...

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(generatePath("http://localhost:5000/api/kam/:id", { id }))
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setData(response.data.kamData);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

To get access to the `id` route match param, import the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) React hook.

```
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { id } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 useEffect(() => {
        let { id } = useParams();
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/kam/${id}`)

            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setData(response.data.kamData);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).